# Woocommerce related product array with user input

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, arguments, woocommerce

I am using the following code as the footer of my single-product.php page in Woocommerce (I've created a "Related Products" section) and I am wondering if there is a way that I can alter it to make it possible for admin to be able to add values from the product admin page; I want certain products to show closer related products instead of totally random ones.

Is there a way I can create a custom field for something like product ID or tag and then add that custom field as the `orderby` value so those products/tags have a better change of showing up vs. random products?

If not, is there anything else I can do? I am simply looking for a way to allow an admin to choose closer related products to appear.

`$args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', array(
    'post_type'            => 'product',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'  => 1,
    'no_found_rows'        => 1,
    'posts_per_page'       => 5,
    'orderby'              => rand,
    'post__in'             => $related,
    'post__not_in'         => array( $product->id )
) );`

[Here is my related-footer.php](http://pastebin.com/k3Dfnf5J)  file with the complete code that includes the above snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can achieve this task as with the following approach:

Create a custom field for the product you want to display a set of your desired related products say the custom field name be "`wdm_related_products`" set the value to a comma separated list of Product ids eg. `46,15,687,21,48`.
Update the product.

Add the following code in functions.php of user child theme or a custom Plugin.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_related_products_args','wdm_custom_related_products',99,1);

function wdm_custom_related_products($array){
global $product;
if(get_post_meta($product->,'wdm_related_products',true)){
$related=get_post_meta($product->id,'wdm_related_products',true);
$array=array(
    'post_type'            => 'product',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'  => 1,
    'no_found_rows'        => 1,
    'posts_per_page'       => 5,
    'orderby'              => rand,
    'post__in'             => $related,
    'post__not_in'         => array( $product->id )
);
}
return $array;
}
```

Let me know it it resolved your issue.

Comment: Hmm nope, it breaks my site when I put it into the functions.php file. There is a link to my related-footer.php file that's found in woocommerce > single-product folder, is there code I need to remove from there?